# Junit5 launcher won't find my Cucumber tests

Tags: cucumber, junit5, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I'm trying to use the Cucumber Junit Platform engine for running my cucumber tests, but none are run.

They're all placed inside `resources/features`.

I have a `RunCucumberTest.java` class:

```
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.integrationtest.steps")
@IntegrationTest
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

The code I use for running the tests is:

```
final LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = request().selectors(selectDirectory("features"))
                .build();
final Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
final TestPlan testPlan = launcher.discover(request);
        logFoundTests(testPlan);

        final SummaryGeneratingListener summaryListener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();
        launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(summaryListener);
        launcher.execute(request);

        summaryListener.getSummary().printTo(new PrintWriter(System.out));
```

This is what gets printed to the console:

```
Test run finished after 56 ms
[         1 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         1 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         1 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         0 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

My tests can be successfully run inside Intellij, both from the feature files themselves or by running the `RunCucumberTest.java` file.
What am I missing here?

Comment: You are using `selectDirectory`, but probably meant to use `selectClasspathResource`.

Comment: Got that from an example in the cucumber documentation... I'll try selectClasspathResource. Would the classpath resource argument still be "features"?

Comment: Yes. The programatic equivalent of`@SelectClasspathResource("features")` is `selectClasspathResource("features")`. It's a bit hard to explain what the classpath is, but everything in `src/{main,test}/{resources}` eventually ends up there (including lots of other stuff).

Comment: This change had no effect, it must be something else.

Comment: Probably a combination of the problem I mentioned and something else then. Can't tell without reproducer project though.

Comment: @PabloFradua did you managed to have it working?